# How to pronounce LINQ?

Tags: pronunciation

How to pronounce LINQ? Or should I just say L-I-N-Q? ([LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594) is a .NET extension for queries.)

Comment: You could pronounce it [liŋq] with a uvular q like the "q" in Iraq. (Though to English ears the k and q sound is indistinguishable). Also C# should be called "see hash", since they insist on using the # (hash) symbol and not the ♯ (sharp) symbol. ;)

Comment: @Stein Never knew that there was a symboy for sharp: ♯. And always wondered why C# is called C "sharp"

Comment: See also: How do I pronounce SQL?

Comment: @SteinG.Strindhaug: The reason they insist on using the # (hash) symbol is that the ♯ (sharp) symbol is not represented on a standard computer keyboard. As for why they chose the name: The name "C sharp" was inspired by musical notation where a sharp indicates that the written note should be made a semitone higher in pitch. This is similar to the language name of C++, where "++" indicates that a variable should be incremented by 1.

Comment: I always saw C# as an evolution on C++ where ++ had another pair of ++ added above it. So C# is C++++...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems the [consensus](http://www.google.com/search?q=pronunciation+linq) [is on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) *"link"*.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query): _**LINQ**, pronounced "link"_

Answer (score 11):

In all the tutorials and according to Wikipedia it's simply pronounced **/lɪŋk/** exactly like link.
It's a Microsoft .NET Framework Component.

Answer (score 3):

As someone posted on Stack Overflow and taken from the mouth of the founder of LINQ himself, take a look at the video under this link (hmmm):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15557254/1654098

And here:

http://www.infoq.com/interviews/erik-meijer-linq

Answer (score 1):

Here's Anders Hejlsberg, lead architect of C#, pronouncing it "link" in 2005:

https://youtu.be/fG8GgqfYZkw?t=74

Answer (score -2):

It is supposed to be pronounced as LINK.

Comment: Can you provide evidence to support your answer?

Comment: and how is LINK supposed to be pronounced?

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Most of people pronounce it Zelda